# Add objects to QGridLayout using a for loop

Tags: python, pyqt5

Hi i'm trying to add objects to a `QGridLayout` using a For loop in python.

In my case, the object is a `QPushButton`

The Grid will be in rows of 3

Here is my current code attempt to make this

```
for i in range(shoes):
                shoebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                shoebtn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 317))
                shoebtn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(280, 317))
                shoebtn.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n""background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);\n""margin-bottom:10px;")
                shoebtn.setText("")
                shoebtn.setObjectName(f"shoeBtn{i}")
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(shoebtn, 0,0,1,1)
```

I think i know what's the issue, and its that `0,0,1,1` at the last line of code, i think it's the positioning on the grid. I'm not really sure how to calculate that. Can someone help out please ? Thanks

Comment: use `self.gridLayout.addWidget(shoebtn, i, 0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):                                   
        super().__init__()
        
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        shoes = 7
        
        row = 0   
        column = 0        
        for i in range(shoes):
            if column == 3:
                column = 0
                row += 1
            shoebtn = QPushButton()                       # (self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            shoebtn.setFixedSize(QSize(50, 50))
            shoebtn.setObjectName(f"shoeBtn{i}")
            shoebtn.clicked.connect(lambda _, text=shoebtn.objectName(): print(f'Clicked {text}'))
            self.gridLayout.addWidget(shoebtn, row, column)

            column += 1

        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                border: none;
                background-color: rgb(140, 140, 240);
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        """)                


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()                            
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! That helped